# Reverse Relation Search Django Admin Interface

Tags: python, database, django, django-admin

Is it possible to do a reverse relation search on the Django Admin interface?

My Django app database schema consists of the following models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name="publications")
```

I have added a search field for looking up tags by title in my admin.py file by doing:

```
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    search_fields = ('title',)
```

Thus, when I type a tag title into the search field on the django admin interface, a list of matching tag titles comes up.  Now I'd like to make it so that if I type a tag title into the search field, matching publications come up.

In other words, I'm imagining something like:

```
 class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    search_fields = ('publications',)
```

Which of course doesn't work... but that's the idea...

Is this even possible? And/or am I even going about this the right way? If so, could someone suggest a way to do this or a resource? If you are kind enough to do so, please keep in mind that I am very much a beginner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to do this using an admin class registered to your Tag model.  Instead, set up an admin class for Publication and set its search_fields:

```
class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title',)
    search_fields = ('tags__title',)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. But what else do I have to do to get this to work? Just making the above edit yields the following error on the admin interface: "FieldError at /admin/apricot_app/publication/
Cannot resolve keyword 'tags_title' into field. Choices are: tags, title".  In other words, how do I get "tags_title" to be recognizeable?

Comment: It looks like you might have mistyped and used a single underscore instead of a double - double underscores are the usual syntax for extending references to related objects in queries.